# How can i make a session control in asp.net so that I can have 2 users logged in at the same time?

Tags: asp.net

So I have a web page where different users with passwords can login. How can i make a session control in asp.net so that I can have 2 users logged in at the same time.

Comment: Come on man, you're not even trying.

Comment: You need to be more specific? What do you mean by session control? By default, no user shares content in controls unless it uses the ApplicationCache

Comment: @Martin, I disagree.  His question is "asp.net"?  The answer is a resounding...Java!  Or Ruby!  Whichever.

Answer (score 2):

You can't share a session between two users. A session, by definition, is a one to one relationship between the server and the user.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you need a single user to be able to log in twice (two different sessions), you can use the CookieLess session mode to better allow that. You have to set the CookieLess setting in the web.config

```
<sessionState cookieless="true" />
```

[msdn article on cookieless sessions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479314.aspx)

Not a helpful edit but this is generally a not very nice solution (the URLs are horrible and hackable)

Answer (score 0):

Kind of a terrible question...but Babak Naffas definition is correct. I guess one solution could be to track sessions in the database

Or even in the one session, track which user instances are logged in